# Does Julia have a strict subtype operator?

Tags: types, julia

**Question:** Does Julia have a strict subtype operator?

**Note:** The operator `<:` is *not* a strict subtype operator, since `Number <: Number` evaluates to `true`. I am interested in an operator that would evaluate to `false` for `Number <: Number` but `true` for `Int <: Number`.

**Possible use case:** Consider a function defined:

```
MyFunc{T<:Union(Int, String)}(x::Array{T, 1}, y::Array{T, 1)})
```

Currently, the function constrains `x` and `y` to be arrays of the same type, where that type is `Int`, `String`, or `Union(Int, String)`. But with a strict subtype operator, I could force the input arrays to be of type `Int` or `String`, and eliminate the (rather odd) `Union(Int, String)` scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is such an operator in Julia, but it would probably be quite easy to write a function that does the same check:

```
strictSubType{T,U}(::Type{T}, ::Type{U}) = T <: U && T != U # note: untested!
```

However, I have to question your use case. If what you really want is something like

```
function my_func{T<:String}(x::Vector{T}, y::Vector{T})
    # handle strings
    # note that String is an abstract type, inherited by e.g. ASCIIString and UTF8String
end

function my_func(x::Vector{Int}, y::Vector{Int})
    # handle ints
    # note that Int is a concrete type (actually an alias for either Int32 or Int64,
    # depending on your platform) so no generic type parameter is necessary
end
```

then write that instead. If you have parts of the logic that can be shared, refactor it out into separate methods, where you can perhaps relax the type parameters (or omit them entirely).

**Update, in response to your comment:**

If the two methods should do *exactly the same thing*, then you're probably better off using [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), and simply not specifying the types of the function arguments at all:

```
funciton my_func(x, y)
    # handle ints, strings and anything else that supports things you need (e.g. > and <)
end
```

Julia will compile specific methods for each type combination you call things for, so you will still get just as fast code; if the function is type stable, then it will be fast for any combination (see the Julia docs for a more thorough explanation of how this works). If you want to make sure that the two arguments are vectors, and that they are of the same type, I'd recommend doing diagonal dispatch (also more thoroughly explained in the docs):

```
function my_func{T}(x::AbstractVector{T}, y::AbstractVector{T})
    # handle stuff
end
```

Note that I use `AbstractVector` rather than `Vector` - this allows using some other container type that also behaves like a vector with elements of type `T`, maximizing the usability of your function for other coders.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for responding. I think I'll follow your suggestion and use my own function for the check. Regarding the use-case, the function I had in mind would be identical for either `String` or `Int` inputs - this can occur when, for example, the function only performs greater than/less than type comparisons, which are valid on both strings and numbers. So it seems wasteful to write out two identical methods (that differ only in the input type). But it would be nice to eliminate the `Union` case since arrays of a `Union` type may suffer performance issues...

Comment: @ColinTBowers: In that case, the more "Julian" way of doing it would be to specify no type at all - then I can use your function with any type I specify (that you don't even know exists), and the only thing required of me is to implement whatever operations your functions need, in this case greater/less than comparisons. The concept is commonly referred to as [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and is considered idiomatic in Julia.

Comment: @ColinTBowers I wrote an update to the post to clarify what I mean. I hope it's helpful =)

Comment: The update is definitely helpful, thank you. It's a new concept to me, so thanks for the Wikipedia link also.